# No agent could be found with the following capabilities:Maven

Tags: tfs

No agent could be found with the following capabilities:Maven Note:- I am able to build in TFS without maven. but when i am adding maven as a build step then I am getting this issue while building. Could anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "maven" listed in your screenshot, make sure the Maven is installed and can run successfully on the build agent. And restart the build service after the Maven is installed. Attached my capabilities for your reference:
[image]

If you are sure that the Maven is installed and can works but the capabilities list still does not show it, you can add it to the capabilities list manually:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the machine running agent, adding system variable with name 'maven' fixes it.
Restarting agent service needed after adding environment variable.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me to get the capability but then the build failed because it needed the M2_HOME variable. So I replaced the maven variable with M2_HOME containing the Maven path (e.g. c:\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your agent can't discover the capability `maven`, follow these steps to fix the issue:

1. Remove the registered agent
2. Go to the environment variables on your server in 'System'
3. Add two variables "MAVEN_HOME" and "M2_HOME" with both as value the installation directory of maven. In my case is this: "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.9"
4. Restart server
5. Register agent again and voila, the agent should have the capability: "MAVEN_HOME", "M2_HOME" and "maven"

Answer (score -1):

The Maven build step requires the build agent to have Maven installed.  The build agent your using must have a capability defined for "Maven".

[image]

FYI - The default hosted agent in VSTS has maven installed.

Read the following blog post for more information on adding capabilities:

http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-register-capabilities-on-your-build-and-release-management-agents

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply. I already added the agent with maven. but still getting same issue  "capabilities not found for maven".

Comment: When you say "with maven", this means you installed maven on the agent and also added the "Maven" capability (not sure if casing matters so make sure it matches) to the agent in TFS as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: Does maven version matters?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sorry.

Comment: there is nothing about maven in screenshot

Comment: The screenshot is showing how you configure capability tags for your agent.  I also added a blog post with more details.